# Upper bound for probability

Tags: probability, statistics, means

Given two i.i.d. random variables $X,Y$ that satisfy the following condition:

1. $P(|X|<0.5)<a$ and
2. $P(|Y|<0.5)<b$

How can I derive an upper bound for the following probability $$P\left(\middle|\frac{X+Y}{2}\middle|<0.5\right)$$ as  a function of $a$ and $b$?
Thanks.

Comment: Are X and Y related or independent?

Comment: Do, you want un upper or a lower bound? In case they are independent you can find a lower bound.

Comment: @JimmyR.  I want an upper bound

Comment: Under these conditions the upper bound is $1$ which is trivial.

Comment: @rbm I added the iid assumption

Comment: $1-\frac{(1-a)^2}2$ (can assume $a=b$).

Comment: @A.S. Interesting, can you please explain me how you got this?

Comment: The max is achived for $X,Y$ concentrated on $-0.5<-d<d<0.5$ with probabilities $\frac {1-a}2$ for $\pm 0.5$ and $\frac a 2$ for $\pm d$. or a similar configuration.